# phalcon php : get element at index

Tags: php, phalcon, volt

How do we get an element at index i in ***.volt** view?

I know this **for loop**

```
{% for robot in robots %}
  {% if robot.type == "cyborg" %}
    {{ robot.name }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

but I would like to print the name of robot at **index 5 only**, and I don't care about other robot names.

Can I access robot at index 5 without using **for loop**?

Answer (score 3):

Volt templates are compiled to PHP code (you can manually check it in the `*.volt.php` files), so you can use similar syntax to access array keys in the loop:

```
{% for key, robot in robots %}
    {% if key == 5 %}
        {{ robot.name }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

or you can use regular PHP syntax to access element by index without loop:

```
{{ robots[5] }}
```

Also, looks like there is a [bug](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/1577) with `object in array` case, so you can use PHP code in the Volt template to resolve your issue without loop:

```
<?php echo $robots[5]->name ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Volt is indeed based on twig but there are some functions which aren't implemented, so you should do better using the original volt documentation: http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/volt.html#variables

Anyways the answer is almost correct, you **can access arrays via index** but keep in mind that the **array index begins with "0"** so the correct answer is:

```
{{ robots[4] }}
```

Comment: The phalcon site says it's based on Jinja, so Volt and Twig seem to be sisters, not mother and daughter.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to access a particular index of an array like this:

```
{{ robots[5] }}
```

Comment: This is actually not…

Comment: Fair enough @IanBytchek. I was making an assumption based on the syntax. I have just removed the link to Twig.